# Java Fontrendering with JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jeditorpane

I want to do some font rendering using the java [html2image-classes](http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/downloads/list). It works fine - but there are some issues that I cannot resolve.

The code I use is the following:

```
import gui.ava.html.image.generator.HtmlImageGenerator;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.LineMetrics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FontTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Throwable
  {
    HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
    imageGenerator.loadHtml("<html>\n" +
"<body bgcolor=green>\n" +
"\n" +
"<span style=\"font-family:'Times New Roman',Times,serif; font-size:200%\">" +
"gro&szlig;er Beispieltext $ in Times New Roman</span>" +
"</body>\n" +
"</html>");
    imageGenerator.saveAsImage("test.png");
  }
}
```

The resulting Image has always 6 pixel too much in width. That issue can be fixed by decreasing the preffered size of the JEditorPane.
The really tricky issue is that the left and the bottom side of the image are containing pixel- rows and colums that I don't want to have within the image.

The are some lines of pixels above the text and some pixel-rows on the left side of the resulting image that shouldn't be a part of the image.
I found out that the amount of "error-pixels" depends on the used font-size.

Does anybody have an idea how to find out the correct (minimal) bounding-box that does only contain the rendered text?

Comment: *"The resulting Image has always 6 pixel too much in width."*  On what basis do you say that?  Note that your example leaves a lot of important details to be decided by the HTML rendering engine.  As such, I suspect that the image is exactly the right size, accounting for default borders/margins inserted by the software.  Note also that HTML was designed to be the exact opposite of PDF.  While PDF is intended to appear *exactly* the same on different machines, HTML is intended to stretch/shrink and flow according to user need (or at least, the container it is displayed in).

Comment: "The resulting Image has always 6 pixel too much in width." I mean it that way:
Let's assume the text to be rendered is "Hello World". When I zoom very deep into the resulting image I see exact 6 rows of pixels after the right edge of the letter "d" within "Hello World". This is not dependent on the font-size.
I guess that the HTML rendering engine is the paint-Method of the underlaying JEditorPane. I am (better: HTML2image classes are) using only this component.